# Proxies in selenium node js

Tags: node.js, selenium, proxy

I have been trying for past few days to build a selenium browser with proxies in node.js. I have researched the topic and none of the provided solutions worked for me because they were deprecated or outdated. I have tried different plugins and methods. Could someone answered me with the correct code example or linked me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')

const PROXY = "190.60.104.218:3128"
const option = new chrome.Options().addArguments(`--proxy-server=http://${PROXY}`)

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(option).build()

driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
  .then(() => console.log('DONE'))
```

Proxy is not anonymous so the original IP is also appearing

[image]

Comment: Okay thank you very much :) do you maybe know also what I would need to change for it to work with proxies that also have usernames and passwords?

Comment: You can simply do with `http://username:password@ip:port`